# Can someone confirm if I did mathematic induction properly?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, induction

So the question is as follows:

> A post office only sells stamps worth $\$3$ and $\$2$. Show that any postage of value greater than $\$2$ can be paid for using only these two stamps.

What I tried: 
I split all numbers greater than two into even and odd numbers and proved each separately.

For even numbers, I used the formula $2n>2$ for $n>2$.

For odd numberss, I used $2n+1>2$ for $n\geq1$.

Is that right or should I use $n=2x+3y$ for $n>2$ like my professor's answer suggest?

Comment: You should use the formula your professor suggests.

Comment: It looks like you are not proving "any value greater than 2c can be paid", but "any value that can be paid is greater than 2c". These are quite different claims.

Comment: Use `$\ge$` for $\ge$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm ah I see. So my formula has to have n>2 rather than just getting a number bigger than 2. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is incomplete with several problems.

1. Your proof does not have the standard form of a proof by induction. The proof by induction should have the following form:

   - This is the claim I am proving (in **strict** mathematical language)
   - This is why the claim is true for $2$
   - This is why the claim is true for $n+1$ if it is true for $n$.

---

2. You claim that you "used" the formula $2n>2$, but that's all you write. So, please explain how the formula $2n>2$ implies that the original claim is true.

---

3. Similarly, how does the formula $2n+1>2$ prove the original claim?

---

My final advice is to indeed listen to your professor's suggestion. In mathematics, as in life, it is often wise to listen to ideas of more experienced people, and of people whose **job** it is to know more than you.

Comment: I proved each one separately in my notebook but I couldn't post pictures here because they were too big, so I just said I proved them. As the person above pointed out, I realize I was proving "any value that can be paid is bigger than 2c" rather than "any value bigger than 2c can be paid. As for my professor's answer, I know it's right; I'm knew to this subject and wasn't sure if there were multiple ways to solve the problem so I just needed clarification

Comment: @NihalMandava I'm not saying that $2n>2$ is a false formula. I am saying that this formula does not prove that you can pay $n$ using the stamps...

Comment: Oh ok, i understand now. Thanks for the help, I corrected my formula to prove I can pay n using the stamps